# Apache Error unexpected shutdown

Tags: apache, xampp, crash

I have been facing this issue with Xampp 5.6.8 where is there is a `Apache Error unexpected shutdown` pop up, asking to "Close program". The moment the pop up message is closed, the service continues normally. I have not noticed any pattern in the error log. Neither there is any particular event that is triggering. The time at which this happens is also not uniform.

Below is the error log that is displayed. Kindly help.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name:         httpd.exe
  Application Version:     2.4.12.0
  Application Timestamp:              54c90386
  Fault Module Name:    php5apache2_4.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.6.8.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:          552ee15f
  Exception Code:             c0000005
  Exception Offset:           00003500
  OS Version:      6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:           1033
  Additional Information 1:           5861
  Additional Information 2:           5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3:           6ee2
  Additional Information 4:           6ee2432e64e99bdcea5e4be767a3b1a2

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```